# Result of Convolve is affected by the GenerateCondition

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, convolution

It is very puzzling to observe that the results of `Convolve` depend on the `GenerateCondition` option and on the names of variables. I am using MA11 on Mac. I advice to execute this piece of code on a fresh kernel.

```
f[ω_]:=1/(ω-ω1-I η)
g[ω_]:=1/(ω-ω2-I η)
Convolve[f[x],g[x],x,y,Assumptions->ω1∈Reals&&ω2∈Reals&&η>0,GenerateConditions->True]
(*  Out[3]= -((2 I π)/(-y+2 I η+ω1+ω2))  *)
```

Well, no conditions has been generated. But the result seems to be reasonable... Let us compare it with the following cases:

---

**Now removing the option** `GenerateConditions`:

```
Convolve[f[x],g[x],x,y,Assumptions->ω1∈Reals&&ω2∈Reals&&η<0]
(*Out[4]= (I π)/(-y+2 I η+ω1+ω2)*)
```

**This result is 2 times smaller (unexpected) and different sign (expected).**

---

```
Convolve[f[x],g[x],x,y,Assumptions->ω1∈Reals&&ω2∈Reals&&η>0]
(*Out[5]= -((I π)/(-y+2 I η+ω1+ω2))  *)
```

**This result is 2 times smaller  (unexpected).**

---

```
Convolve[f[x],g[x],x,y,Assumptions->ω0∈Reals&&ω1∈Reals&&η ϵ Reals]
(* Out[6]= (I π)/(-y+2 I η+ω1+ω2) *)
```

**This result is 2 times smaller (unexpected). The sign corresponds to the `η<0` case (strange choice, but let us respect it).**

---

**Changing the names of parameters should not matter, right?**

```
Clear[f,g]
f[ω_]:=1/(ω-a-I η)
g[ω_]:=1/(ω-b-I η)
```

Now do the same calculations

```
Convolve[f[x],g[x],x,y,Assumptions->a∈Reals&&b∈Reals&&η>0,GenerateConditions->True]
(* Out[10]= -((2 I π)/(a+b-y+2 I η)) *)
```

**As before (expected).**

---

```
Convolve[f[x],g[x],x,y,Assumptions->a∈Reals&&b∈Reals&&η>0]
(* Out[11]= -((2 I π)/(a+b-y+2 I η)) *)
```

**Voila, both calculations agree (unexpected)!**

*Conclusion: use the right names and the result be correct, otherwise, it depends on the `GenerateCondition` option.*  Suspect a bug.

Comment: If you replace eta with a latin character (a, b, c, ö, etc), you always get 2*pi*i in the numerator.  And if you replace eta with any special character (greeks, \\[FilledSquare], etc), the behavior you show occurs.  So I suppose the condition for the failure is if eta and one of omega1 or omega2 are special characters and GenerateConditions is False, then you lose the 2 from the numerator.  I'll have to work out a more general version in the morning.

Comment: @fp.monkey Thanks for the interest in this problem. Really weird behavior, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You may find the difference easier to understand if you write the convolution as an integral.  The position of the pole relative to the real line depends on the sign of `η`.  With `η=0` the pole is on the real line, and the integral diverges (but you can take its principal value, which is zero).

```
Assuming[{ω1, ω2, y, η} ∈ Reals && η > 0, 
 Integrate[f[x] g[y - x], {x, -∞, ∞}]]
(* -((2 I π)/(-y + 2 I η + ω1 + ω2)) *)

Assuming[{ω1, ω2, y, η} ∈ Reals && η < 0, 
 Integrate[f[x] g[y - x], {x, -∞, ∞}]]
(* (2 I π)/(-y + 2 I η + ω1 + ω2) *)

Assuming[{ω1, ω2, y, η} ∈ Reals && η == 0, 
 Integrate[f[x] g[y - x], {x, -∞, ∞}, 
  PrincipalValue -> True]]

(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Nice to know that `Integrate` works.  But why do you say that `GenerateConditions` is not helpful? After all it allows to get the right answer. Without it the answer is 2 times smaller if `ω1` and `ω2` are used and the same if `a` and `b` are used instead.

Comment: You are right, I should have read your question more carefully.  I've deleted the statement about `
`GenerateConditions`